# How do I add start session in pyramid framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, deform

I'm beginner of pyramid framework.I tried to start a session in application but session not working.Here is the following code:
init.py

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator    
from pyramid.session import SignedCookieSessionFactory
def main(global_config, **settings):
    my_session_factory = SignedCookieSessionFactory('itsaseekreet')
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)     
    config.set_session_factory(my_session_factory)
    config.add_route('next', '/next')
```

views.py

```
@view_config(route_name="next")
def next(request):
try:            
    query=request.dbsession.query(UserMaster)
    global user_id,password
    user_id=request.params['uname']
    password=request.params['password']
    session=request.session
    session['username']=user_id
    two=query.filter(UserMaster.user_id==user_id,UserMaster.password==password).first()
    if two is None:
        print('Invaid Username or password')
        return render_to_response('../templates/login.jinja2', {}, request=request)
    else:       
           return render_to_response('../templates/menu.jinja2', {})

except DBAPIError:
    return Response(db_err_msg, content_type='text/plain', status=500)

@view_config(route_name='index')
def index(request):
try:
    name = request.session.get('username')
    return render_to_response('../templates/index.jinja2', {'name':name},   request=request)
except DBAPIError:
    return Response(db_err_msg, content_type='text/plain', status=500)

@view_config(route_name='logout', renderer='../templates/login.jinja2')
def logout(request):
try:
    request.session().invalidate()
except DBAPIError:
    return Response(db_err_msg, content_type='text/plain', status=500)
```

I got TypeError: 'CookieSession' object is not callable

Comment: There is no data in the session object at the place where you have `if 'user_id' in session`.

Comment: Yea.Thanks for your response.How do i add session object?

Comment: added fred session object Steve Piercy

Comment: First improve your code formatting. Next instead of copy-pasting from the Pyramid narrative docs on [Sessions](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/sessions.html), spend time walking through the 21 Lessons in the [Quick Tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/sessions.html) or [SQLAlchemy + URL Dispatch Wiki Tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/) both of which provide working examples. Then you can apply what you have learned to your code. SO is not the place to debug your code.